# How to return 2 values from a function

Tags: python, function, return

I am having difficulty understanding why my function does not store the I value that I append onto a list?

The code is:

```
def numberofdays ():
    sum = 0
    leapyears = []
    for i in range (1901, 2000):
            if i%4 == 0:
                leapyears.append (i)
                sum = sum + 366

            else:
                sum = sum + 365
    return sum + 366  #to account for year 2000.
    return leapyears
```

When I call `print numberofdays()`, it only returns `36525`, the `sum` value.

Comment: Your title was mistaken so I fixed it. The leapyear values i *were* getting stored correctly in leapyears; your only problem was how to make your return statement return multiple values.

Comment: By the way, you are kludging `return sum + 366  #to account for year 2000`. You could fix that by making a helper fn `is_leap_year(yr)` which first returns True for yr==2000, then returns `(yr%4 == 0)`. Then your `number_of_days()` only has to `return (sum, leapyears)`. You should check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

Using `return` immediately exits a function.  Meaning, the `return leapyears` line will never be reached because of the `return sum + 366` line directly above it.

If you want to return two values from `numberofdays`, you can put them in a tuple and return that:

```
return sum + 366, leapyears
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> def func():
...     return 1, 2
...
>>> func()
(1, 2)
>>> a, b = func()  # You can use iterable unpacking to give the values names
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>>
```

Also, as @JonClements said in his comment, it looks like you actually meant to do `range (1901, 2001)` instead of `range (1901, 2000)`.  Remember that the second argument to `range` is always exclusive (not included).

Finally, you can replace code such as `sum = sum + 366` with just `sum += 366`.  This is really a minor issue, but the latter approach is more pythoic. ;)

Comment: Thank you! So if I want to call the leapyears list, would I have to say something like second numberofdays()?

Comment: What do you mean by "call the leapyears list"?  You cannot call a list.

Comment: Also seems odd to special case `2000` - might want to just change to `range (1901, 2001)`...

Comment: Yup I have changed that, that was because of a mistake with my understanding of the question. I mean if I want to check whether a number is a member of the leapyear list in another function? Sorry I'm used to coding in another language than python!

Comment: @Gong I'll just note that you're re-inventing the wheel here (plus your leap year calculation logic is wrong) - see https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.isleap - just use that where you want to check... I don't see much point in having a list of leap years hanging about just to check something's a leap year

Comment: @Gong you might always want to look at Python's datetime - eg `from datetime import date; days = (date(2001, 1, 1) - date(1901, 1, 1)).days` will return the number of days between two dates (in this case whole years.... - if you're dealing with seconds etc..., the above might not work)

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statements ends the function - as soon as it hits the `return`, it's all over.

To return multiple values, you can `return (sum+366,leapyears)`